# Placing listview in Getview method in Android

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I have a custom list created with getView method, and i want to place another custom listview in each row on that custom list. Which should look like:

- Row1
- List
- Text1 Text2
- Text1 Text2
- Text1 Text2

---

- Row2
- List
- Text1 Text2
- Text1 Text2
- Text1 Text2

---

- Row3
- List
- Text1 Text2
- Text1 Text2
- Text1 Text2

But it seems i can't add another getview method into main getView. Does someone has any suggestion? Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
public static class ChildAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;       
     public IrrigationAdapter(Context context) {
               mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }
    public int getCount() {
                return array.size();
                }
     public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position;
                }
     public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }       
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row1, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.Text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                            holder.Text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);                         
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }   
               holder.Text1.setText(sulamaDonemArr.get(position));
                   holder.Text2.setText(bitkiDesenArr.get(position));

       return convertView;
       }    

         static class ViewHolder {      
              TextView Text1;
              TextView Text2;                
            }               
        }

private static class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     public SulamaDetayAdapter(Context context) {
               mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);                   
                }
     public int getCount() {
                return arraysize;
                }
     public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position;
                }
     public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }       
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;                
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_sulamabaslama_detay, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text1= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                    holder.childAdapterList.setAdapter(????);


                    convertView.setTag(holder);                                         
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }                       

       return convertView;
       }

         static class ViewHolder {      
              TextView text1,text2;               
              ListView childAdapterList;
            }
```

}

It is something like this now

Comment: Do you really need listview for your row views? You can't just use tableView or regural layouts contains static views like you described ?

Comment: I edited it, listview must be dynamic

Comment: what solution you had ?? I'm doing the same thing but in rough wat..i.e getview -> listview -> new adapter for listview....something like that..any other idea??

Answer (score 0):

You can use expandable list view on each row. So that you can perform as similar you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for  [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: I edited the question, don't you think i can solve it without using expandable listview?

Comment: you can move context to getview like this private static class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;
 Context _context;
   public SulamaDetayAdapter(Context context) {
       _context = context;

Comment: is this some part of the answer? :)